# How to use bbding package?

Tags: fonts, symbols, enumitem

I tried to use `bbding` package for the `enumitem` symbols. I have added to my code:

```
\usepackage{bbding}
....
\begin{itemize}[label=\HandRight]
```

but I receive error

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex (file bbding10):
 Font bbding10 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I have a complete version of `texlive` on Ubuntu. What other stuff is needed to put `bbding` in action?

UPDATE: The question was updated by useful comments in answers. As `egreg` assisted to figure it out; the problem was connected to user permission, as `texlive` had been installed under root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbols are not math symbols, so `$` is out of place.

You might want to correct the vertical placement of the symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,bbding,etoolbox,calc}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chooseSymbol}{\raisebox{-.5ex}[\height-.5ex][0pt]}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\HandRight]
\item abc

\item[\PencilRight] def
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is not vertical placement, but fonts. As I stated on the other answer, I get error `Font bbding10 at 600 not found` even with your code. Probably something is missing on my system; though I've complete version of texlive.

Comment: @Ali Try issuing `mktexpk bbding10` from the terminal. What happens?

Comment: `/root/.texlive2011/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/bbding/bbding10.600pk already exists.`

Comment: Are you *really* using your system as `root`?

Comment: yes, I am root. This is a server, not desktop computer.

Comment: @Ali Then *no* user will be able to use the created bitmaps. *Never* use TeX as root; do only maintenance.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to install the (Ubuntu) package `texlive-fonts-extra`.  Since I found this unanswered question while trying to resolve the same issue myself, I though it worth sharing what worked for me, despite the question being a little old.

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this and don't use `$...$`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\HandRight]
    \item Test
    \item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error stating `!pdfTeX error: /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex (file bbding10):
 Font bbding10 at 600 not found`

Comment: @Ali Do you get this error when you're running my code or yours?

Comment: Your code, exactly the whole code you introduced. I don't have this problem with other packages such as `wasysym`, `pifont`, etc; but `bbding`. This is the reason that I tried `$`.

Comment: @Ali I guess that there's a problem with your TeX Live installation.

Comment: `bbding` uses bitmap fonts, which are built on demand. The problem might be in some setting of your TeX Live. Did you try any customization?

Comment: @egreg This is what makes me wonder. I've fresh installation of vanilla texlive with no customization. Particulary, as I does not have this problem with any other package like `pifont`, `MnSymbol`, `wasysym`, etc.